# Meaning of 注意 in the context of advice

Tags: meaning

> みなさん、夏休みのすごし方で**注意すること**を発表して下さい。
>   Everyone, please present the things you would *advise* for ways to spend the summer holidays.

I often get confused with the meaning of 注意. Given that 注意 can also mean 'warn/caution' etc. I assumed that when it means 'advice' it is in the sense of 'if you don't take my advice it would be a poor decision'. But, this sentence just seems to be asking for suggestions on nice ways to spend the summer holidays. Have I misunderstood the sentence? What does 注意 actually mean?

Comment: It can be assumed that this is a sentence which a presentator gives tutors. I imagin 花火、プール 過ごし方 so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This 注意 is simply "caution" in the sense of "If you don't follow this, a bad thing can happen to you." Typical 夏休みの注意 given at school are:

- 繁華街やデパートに子どもだけで行かないこと。 (or you may receive guidance from a police officer)
- 水辺など危険な場所へは立ち入らないこと。 (or you may drown)
- 夜はちゃんと布団をかけて寝ること。 (or you may catch a cold)

If you are thinking of "advice" such as 15日は花火大会に行くと楽しいはず, then that's not what the teacher is asking about.

Comment: @chocolate ありがとうございます…w

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't think of 「注意」 as "advice" at all like　the words 「アドバイス」 or 「助言」.
I think the closest translation to　「注意する」 that you can think of in any case is "*beware*" or "*warn*".  So in the case of your sentence:

> みなさん、夏休みのすごし方で注意することを発表して下さい。 = Please all, present the things you would warn somebody about as a way of spending summer vacations.

Answer (score 1):

> 注意すること

I think this is like 注意事項｛ちゅういじこう｝ which means:
important points; precautions; points to note; suggestions; hints.

> But, this sentence just seems to be asking for suggestions on nice ways to spend the summer holidays.

In this sense, your guess is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

> this sentence just seems to be asking for suggestions on nice ways to spend the summer holidays. Have I misunderstood the sentence?

Almost OK. In this case, **注意する** is a intransitive verb which means "take care" or "pay attention". The speaker (maybe a teacher) wants to let them (maybe students) present the things that *they each* would take care of to let them find the things by themselves.

> みなさん、夏休みのすごし方で注意することを発表して下さい。

It means "Everyone, please present the things you would take care of to spend the summer holidays".